# How do I create a popup Angular component with parameters?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How do I create a popup Angular 1.6 component that accepts several parameters and will be used in several pages. One of the parameters will be dynamic -- set in the ng-click that opens the popup.

The popup scope should be a child scope of the calling page (not isolate), and it should have outputs back to the calling page.

Anyone know of a good pattern for that?

Answer (score 0):

It mainly depends on what front-end framework are you using: if you go for Bootstrap than search for [Bootstrap's Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals); if you are using Angular Material than it's called [Dialog](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog).

And in terms of how to set up the logic for it, well, there are quite a variety of options here as well. The simplest one I can think of would be to:

- bind any variables from the `popup` using ng-model AND
- pass it to a service and have custom logic OR in $rootScope OR in Location

This would be just a simple exammple. 
Again, I think it mainly depends on what you actually want to achieve, which is not quite clear. I hope this helps.

Comment: That helps, thanks. I'll try putting all the params into an object, instantiate a popup that uses the Angular Material Dialog in the template, and then see about returning a promise with a response object from the dialog.